# Give a page priority over a category that has the same name?

Tags: categories, pages, hierarchical

Is there a way to give preference to a page with the same name as a category?

(edit added some context)

I have a page that links to four different sub-categories, that page has a template applied to it so that it looks different from a normal category page that would otherwise just display posts. However I also have a category with the same name because I don't want the url's of the sub categories to not have the parent name in their URL's.

So my issue is that the category slug is taking over from the page and displaying all the sub-category posts in one page. Therefore I'd like a way to preference to the template page.

Thanks

Comment: There should be some context to your question.  Otherwise, a simple "Yes" response could be considered a valid answer.

Comment: Sorry the context is a bit hard to describe and I thought it would be a pretty straight forward answer.

Comment: if the purpose of the page is only to assign a template, you can just use a [template filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#filter-hierarchy) to force a specific template for your category instead.

Comment: Tried that but I'm getting the default loop and then the bottom of the template page?

Comment: what milo said... override the loop for those categories

Comment: Also my template has things like CMB2 fields.